# How to mock collections in Meteor (using Jest)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, jestjs

I'm learning how to test `meteor` apps using `jest`. I'm using [this article](https://www.okgrow.com/posts/real-world-unit-testing-with-meteor-and-jest). The problem is that I'm not sure how to stub collections other than `Meteor.users`.

The article provides an example:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
const Performance = new Mongo.Collection('performance');
Performance._ensureIndex({
  userId: 'text',
});
export default Performance;
```

However, I'm not sure about where to put this code. According to the article, all modules' mocks should be found in

```
.meteorMocks/index.js
```

Where should I define a collection mock, so that it wouldn't interfere with meteor code?

I cannot declare it in `.meteorMocks/index.js` because there go modules' mocks.

Comment: To Stubcollections you can (and should) use [hwillson:stub-collections](https://github.com/hwillson/meteor-stub-collections). To stub other objects, suchs as `Meteor.user()` you can use [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/), which is also available as meteor package. Maybe this works, so you don't need to use the `.meteorMocks`